# Should I use App_Themes or Content/themes in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, themes, app-themes

Up until now I had been using MVC3 for my apps but with the new update of Visual Studio 2012 I got MVC4. I migrated a few of my apps and now they are broken.

I noticed that the new project template for an Internet application creates a ~/Content/themes/base folder.

And yet, up until now I had been accustomed to use the App_Themes folder for that. In fact, with VS.2013 you can use "Add ASP.NET FOlder | Themes".

So I am now confused with MVC4, has It deprecated the App_Themes folder (which seems more appropriate to me than ~/Content) ? or is there a significant difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App_Theme come from ASP.NET Platform and one goal of mvc is get a clean html code

> One of the things that ASP.NET MVC is missing is the ability to
>   easily implement Themes. The older, more mature standard ASP.NET
>   framework includes theme support via the App_Themes folder; however
>   limited it can be, it’s still more than ASP.NET MVC currently has.
>   Well, at least until I wrote this little custom ViewEngine and
>   ControllerBase class to help out and allow us to very easily implement
>   Themes within our ASP.NET MVC applications

take a look this helpful article [this link](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I had been some months since I was doing MVC... BTW I had a similar problem like the one you described, I needed themes AND localization but all the custom theme engines I saw (worst when added localization) required duplicating (even multiplicating) layouts and other stuff. So I took the best from several solutions out there (including a custom theme engine), modified it and ended up with one that did not require multiplication (per theme) of layouts and other files just for supporting themes.

Comment: Don't quite remember if the pages theme="xxx" attribute in web.config can be used to configure the MVC theme or not. Disregard, just read it applies to the former ASP.NET themeing (App_Theme) types of pages.

Comment: in fact, if you want work with more freedom, custom engine's are required, I write my own controller factory, view engine. good luck!